# Migração de MySQL para Mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Tenho um servidor MySQL que possui diversos bancos; alguns gigantescos. Estive estudando e vi que vários serviços migraram de MySQL para MariaDB. Como trata-se de um fork, eu poderia simplesmente migrar estes dados de um servidor para outro ou devo tomar alguma precaução além do óbvio backup de dados?

Comment: pode migrar sem problemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumindo que você use versões equivalentes mysql-mariadb você poderia sim migrar sem nenhum problema pois mariadb é [backwards compatible](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibilidade_reversa) com mysql, só tenha certeza de ter feito backups antes.